# Restart the bluetooth swith alfter closed it, my app can not discover the services form the ble peripheral

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

My app can not get the ble peripheral's services when restart the `bluetooth` switch on `iphone`.We must restart the iphone when this problem is appearing to solve it.

I think there is some code broken after I turn off the `bluetooth` when the peripheral is work? Then the delegate method :

`(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)`

error do not call back after I user the `[_peripheral discoverServices:nil]`

Comment: Did you released the _peripheral in the disconnection? Even with killing the app and restarting it there is this problem?

Comment: @Larme, I am having the same issue. Killing the app wont work, you have to restart the phone or go resetting all your settings. Appearently some cache has been stored somewhere.